# Capturing a Screenshot of a Flash Application loaded in the browser

Tags: c#, c++, flash, screenshot

I would like to know is it possible to access the flash application object loaded in the default web browser and programatically get a screenshot of the application only.

Comment: Why? What is your actual requirement?

Comment: you mean a certain flash app or any .swf?

Comment: requirement? uhm i can put it in a way of 'automation', type of research. wondering whether its possible, and its mainly for knowledge.

Comment: Yes, for the moment its targeted for a specific swf.
if you can provide a code that works on any swf thats awesome.

Comment: There could be multiple browsers open with multiple tabs with multiple swf's in each of them running. Which one would you like a screenshot of? Or are you merely interested in the swf, and can we skip the browser by hosting the flash activex directly?

Comment: Why not use screen scraping?  You can do that programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `BitmapData.draw(/*your main displayobject*/)` inside an swf